# Why does my IDEA not open a new window but jump to the current window when entering the class

Tags: intellij-idea

Why does my IDEA not open a new window but jump to the current window when entering the class

I can't find the Settings....

Answer (score 0):

Looks the same as this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304419/.

The IDEA will reuse the preview tab when you are using the "Go To Declaration or Usages" feature.

Try to click the setting icon in Project tool window, and disable the preview tab feature there.
Or you could open the `Help | Find Action` from the main menu, type `Registry...`, select it and in the opened list, find and disable the `editor.preview.tab.navigation` to disable this behavior.

[image: how to disable the preview tab]